# Very slow text file spliting in JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, optimization

I have a GUI from which I want to open a file. The logic is as follows: first, the program asks for a directory in which it creates a new folder for temporary files. Then, it asks for a file which has the data (one line of that file looks like this for instance: -20 -20 2435.5 2421.4 ). Then the program proceeds to split that file into smaller text files. It does what I want, but it takes really long. I have no idea on how to make it faster. Can anyone give me any pointers, or explain, why does it take so long? I've used the method for splitting the file before, outside the GUI, and I didn't have this problem, so I guess that the GUI is responsible in this case.
I'd be grateful for any help.

Source code:

```
public void OpeningFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File folder;
    String filepath;
    Object[] options = {"Ok","Cancel"};  

    int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
        "Choose a folder in which temporary files will be created, \n then open a text file with Raman Mapping",
        "Information",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
        null,
        options,
        options[1]);

    if (n == 0) {

    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fc.setApproveButtonText("Stwórz");
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(Main.this);


    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        folder = fc.getSelectedFile();
        filepath=folder.getAbsolutePath();
        File newFolder=new File(filepath+"/Temp_Raman");
        newFolder.mkdir();

        int returnVal2 = fc2.showOpenDialog(Main.this);


        if (returnVal2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           dane=fc2.getSelectedFile();
           String dane1=dane.getAbsolutePath();
           System.out.println(dane1);
           System.out.println(filepath);
           divideTxt(dane, filepath);
        }
        else{ 
            System.out.println("Cancelled");
        }

    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println("Cancelled");
    }



           // ZAMYKANIE PLIKU:
           try {
             fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }
      else{           
        System.out.println("cancelled");       
        }

}

private static void divideTxt(File dane, String filepath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

       List<Integer> XX= new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Integer> YY= new ArrayList<Integer>();


       int a=1;
       List<Integer> x= new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Integer> y= new ArrayList<Integer>();
       List<Double> t= new ArrayList<Double>();
       List<Double> u= new ArrayList<Double>();


       Scanner sc = new Scanner(dane);
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
              x.add(sc.nextInt());
              y.add(sc.nextInt());
              t.add(sc.nextDouble());
             u.add(sc.nextDouble());
              //sc.nextLine();
          }




       File danePodzielone=new File(filepath+"/Temp_Raman/dane"+a+".txt");
       danePodzielone.createNewFile();
       XX.add(x.get(0));
       YY.add(y.get(0));
       for(int i=0;i<x.size()-1;i++)
       {

           if(x.get(i+1) !=x.get(i)){
               a++;
               danePodzielone=new File(filepath+"/Temp_Raman/dane"+a+".txt");
               danePodzielone.createNewFile();
               XX.add(x.get(i+1));
           }
           else {
           if(y.get(i+1)!=y.get(i)){
               a++;
               danePodzielone=new File(filepath+"/Temp_Raman/dane"+a+".txt");
               danePodzielone.createNewFile();
               YY.add(y.get(i+1));
           }
           else{
              FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filepath+"/Temp_Raman/dane"+a+".txt",true);


              PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
              pw.write(t.get(i)+" "+u.get(i)+"\n");
              pw.flush();
              pw.close();
           }
           }
        }

      }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  Have the code generate the input file.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.  3) *"`// ZAMYKANIE PLIKU:`"*  These type of comments are completely useless to someone who does not understand the language.  Please translate to English.  4) Is the file splitting fast when done from the command line?

Comment: try putting in some timestamp debugging output so you can see where the code is slow.

Comment: if your splitting code is fast and it's slow after adding the GUI, why are you posting the splitting code instead of your GUI code? :-)